# Relation migrating after targetEntity changed in ManyTone

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I changed this code

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Member", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $member;
```

By

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $member;
```

I need now migrate the old Member ids to the good User ids. Unfortunately, i can't find a way to get old ids i tried

```
$subscription->getMember()->getId()
```

which is null

i tried too

```
$subscription->getMemberId()
```

Thks for help

Answer (score 0):

Do you renamed the Entity Member to User and kepp the same mysql (or whatever) table or do you change mysql table too?

If you change table, you have to play directly with your dbrm to upgrade your data.

Comment: i changed the entity Member to User then i made a schema update.
But i need to update relation keys cause they are related to Member entity  and not User

Comment: Ok, don't use php to do that. An UPDATE query in your database will sove your problem.